# View error in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using python to create a dummy server storing JSON data. I'm trying to fetch the data to display it in a dashboard. I keep getting

> cannot read property html of undefined

and

> cannot read property render of undefined

What am I missing?

My backbone script:

```
// Create a Model
var Dashboard = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Create a collection
var DashboardCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Dashboard,
  url: 'http://localhost:8889/api/test'
});

// create an instance of the collection object
var jobList = new DashboardCollection();
    jobList.fetch({success:function(){
            test.render();
        }});
        // Create a jobList view
var jobListView= Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.jobsList'),
    template: _.template($('#test-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        //this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        //this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },
    render : function(){

        this.$el.html(this.template({'last_name':'test'}));
        return this;
    }
 });

var test = new jobListView;
```

And my HTML:

```
    <main>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="left glass">
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <div class="legacy-ie-fix"></div>
                <![endif]-->
                <h1>Job List</h1>
                <div class ="jobsList">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right glass">
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <div class="legacy-ie-fix"></div>
                <![endif]-->
                <h1>Metrics</h1>
                <div id="metrics">
                    <div class="row">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
<script type="text/template" id="test-template">
    <table class="table striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><%= last_name %></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: Your calling `test.render()` before initializing test. Aside from that you probably want to use an `id`selector for *jobsList* or pass in the element to the view.

Comment: You should include the full error message in your question, in addition to a [mcve].

Comment: Try moving `jobList.fetch(...` after `var test = new jobListView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an ordering problem.

## Make sure the document is ready

If you use jQuery in your script to grab an element from the document (like `el: $('.jobsList')`), you must ensure that the HTML is ready. You can wrap your code in a jQuery style document ready function:

```
$(function() {
    var JobListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('.jobsList'),
        template: _.template($('#test-template').html()),

        render: function() {

            this.$el.html(this.template({ 'last_name': 'test' }));
            return this;
        }
    });

});
```

Or just load the scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` but inside of it.

```
    <script type="text/template" id="test-template">
       Put the template above the scripts loading and inside the body.
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.js">
    <script src="underscore.js">
    <script src="backbone.js">
    <script src="script/my-app.js">
</body>
```

The order of the `<script>` tags on the page is important. Backbone requires jQuery and Underscore.js to be loaded before and your own code requires Backbone (and jQuery, but that's already taken care of in the dependency chain).

## Declare and assign variable before using them

You call `fetch` on the collection, which uses the view before it is assigned. While it could work (see [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)), it's best to declare and assign variables before using them when possible.

```
// Create a list view class
var JobListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.jobsList', // no need to use jQuery here.
    template: _.template($('#test-template').html()),

    render: function() {

        this.$el.html(this.template({ 'last_name': 'test' }));
        return this;
    }
});

// instantiate the view first.
var test = new JobListView();

// then create an instance of the collection object
var jobList = new DashboardCollection();

// and fetch it when everything is ready.
jobList.fetch({
    success: function() {
        test.render();
    }
});
```

Notice that JS custom types (classes) should be in `PascalCase` rather than in `snakeCase` as a generally approved standard, but that's not going to make the code fail.

## Pass the element to the view

To be able to easily reuse your views within different views and templates, you should avoid hard-coding the `el` property.

Instead, pass the element to the view:

```
var JobListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ... 
});

// ...somewhere else

var view = new JobListView({ el: '.jobsList' });
```

Or use the element created by a Backbone view.

```
var JobListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'jobList',
});

// ...inside a parent view's render
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: '<div class="job-list-1"></div><div class="job-list-2"></div>',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.$('.job-list-1').html(new JobListView().render().el);
        this.$('.job-list-2').html(new JobListView().render().el);
        // ...
        return this;
    }
});
```

This would result in:

```
<div class="job-list-1">
    <div class="jobList"></div>
</div>
<div class="job-list-2">
    <div class="jobList"></div>
</div>
```